# Angular 2 Child route module display the correct url but displays another component

Tags: angular, routes

I cleaned up my root route file, by creating a child custom module for routes, and here is the script:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';

const childRoutes: Routes = [

    {path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent},

    {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(childRoutes)
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class ChildRoutingModule { }
```

The root route module now is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent } from './auth/signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './auth/signup/signup.component';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './notfound/notfound.component';
import { ChildRoutingModule } from './auth/auth.route'

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo:'/signup', pathMatch:'full'},

    {path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I imported the 2 route modules into the app.module.ts:

```
import ...
import ...
import { AppRoutingModule } from './routes'
import { ChildRoutingModule } from './auth/auth.route'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    ChildRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AuthModule,
    RouterModule 
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The problem now is on the startup component of the app that is the signup component, the url is correct: `http://localhost:4200/signup` but the displayed component is the 404 component which is defined in the root route component by `{path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent}`

**To mention that no errors are displayed at the console at all**

Comment: instead of  redirectTo:'/signup', 

use  redirectTo:'signup',

and try again.

Comment: Nope. Still the same issue

Comment: Change this as: 

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AuthModule,
    RouterModule,
    ChildRoutingModule, 
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but why should I import the root route module at the end

Comment: Will you please accept my answer than.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `AppRoutingModule` last. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#routing-module-order

Comment: So always the root route should be imported last, so it will not interfere with the routes of the childs ?

Comment: Yes, since you have a wild card route `{path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent}` this will catch the request before the other routes.

Answer (score 1):

Change this as:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AuthModule,
    RouterModule,
    ChildRoutingModule, 
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
```

You need to load AppRoutingModule at last , because before that route routes needs to know all the child routes , to make routing deep level on init time.

Or it will redirect to the Error Component as you have defined.

Comment: This is incorrect, the OP's error is due to the fact that routes are added in a sequence and if you have something that might that fetch your request (in OP's case a wildcard `{path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent}`) it will use that route instead.

Comment: Yes I have also , explained that , the order was wrong.